# Visual 2012 constantly loading and unloading syswow64

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-debugging, syswow64

I run my app in the debugger. Everything's fine for a bit, and then without fail Visual begins outputting this:

```
'Syntorial.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ExplorerFrame.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'Syntorial.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\duser.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'Syntorial.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\dui70.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'Syntorial.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\dui70.dll'
'Syntorial.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\duser.dll'
'Syntorial.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ExplorerFrame.dll'
'Syntorial.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ExplorerFrame.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'Syntorial.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\duser.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'Syntorial.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\dui70.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'Syntorial.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\dui70.dll'
'Syntorial.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\duser.dll'
'Syntorial.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ExplorerFrame.dll'
etc...........
```

And it doesn't stop until I restart the debugger. My app plays video and audio and this constant output creates hiccups in the audio. Not to mention that whenever I output any text it gets lost in this sea of unloading/loading making it difficult to find. Any ideas?